# wordpress plugin setting page not enqueueing jquery?

Tags: jquery

on a setting page for my custom plugin i ahve the following:

```
function wbvpe_load_scripts($hook) {
    global $wbvpe_settings_page;
    if( $hook != $wbvpe_settings_page ) 
    return;

    wp_register_script('search', plugins_url('search.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), null, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('search');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wbvpe_load_scripts', 20, 1);
```

When viewing the source of the page i can see the above gets outputted correctly.

However there is no trace of jquery being loaded?

I added the following to see what was happening:

```
$wpScripts = new WP_Scripts();
if($wpScripts->query('jquery','enqueued')){
    echo 'enqueued';
} else { echo 'not enqueued';}

if($wpScripts->query('jquery','registered')){
     echo ' - registered';
} else { echo ' - not registered';}
```

The output was:

```
not enqueued - registered
```

So jquery is getting registered but not enqueued. I tried to enqueue jquery again like this:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

But still nothing! Any ideas what the issue could be?

This is the only jwery i can see getting loaded:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://xxxxxxx/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=0&amp;load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&amp;ver=3.9'></script>
```

Comment: Are you sure jQuery isn't being loaded in the header? It's likely that another script has enqueued it. Also, is this causing your search script not to work?

Comment: Added script i found in the header to my original question, and yes search script not working correctly

Comment: What exactly is the error in your search script?

Comment: all i can see in the dom is that jquery is not loaded

Comment: Try naming it something other than search

Comment: Are you using `$` or `jQuery` in your own script? WordPress loads jQuery with `load-scripts.php` in no conflict mode.

Comment: How do you "see in the dom" that jQuery is not loaded? Is it 404? Did you load it from some CDN or did you use the default one? Disable all other plugins and switch to one of the Twenty* themes to make sure that this is not the problem.

Comment: solved this now! i was using jQuery, but missed a $ hidden in my script!